# Android back button closes app

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm showing a local html file in a `WebView` which is the center node of a Glisten `View`. When I presss the android back button, instead of going back to the previous view, the app gets closed. When I use an appBar button to switch to the previous view it works fine. 
I tried to attach an event filter to both, webView and scene, but it doesn't get triggered.

javafxports version: 8.60.6

**UPDATE:**

The issue occures only when the webview is focused.

```
public class ImportHelpPresenter extends BasePresenter {

    @FXML
    private WebView web;

    @Override
    protected void initialize() {
        super.initialize();
        web.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        loadHelpPage();
    }

    private void loadHelpPage() {
        String htmlContent = null;
        try {
            htmlContent = readContent("importhelp.html");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        web.getEngine().loadContent(htmlContent);
    }

    String readContent(String fileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    EventHandler<? super KeyEvent> backButtonFilter = evt -> {
        System.out.println(evt);
        if (KeyCode.ESCAPE.equals(evt.getCode())) {
            evt.consume();
            showPreviousView();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onShown() {
        super.onShown();
        web.getScene().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, backButtonFilter);
        web.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, backButtonFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHidden() {
        web.getScene().removeEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, backButtonFilter);
        web.removeEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, backButtonFilter);
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
04-19 04:49:54.760: V/InternalWebView(11536): WebView added to ViewGroup [x: 0, y: 84 , w: 480 h: 678]
04-19 04:49:54.760: V/InternalWebView(11536): Loading content: <html>
//content omitted
04-19 04:49:54.930: D/webcoreglue(11536): netstack: Memory Cache feature is ON
04-19 04:49:55.070: V/chromium(11536): external/chromium/net/host_resolver_helper/host_resolver_helper.cc:66: [0419/044955:INFO:host_resolver_helper.cc(66)] DNSPreResolver::Init got hostprovider:0x51d36010
04-19 04:49:55.070: V/chromium(11536): external/chromium/net/base/host_resolver_impl.cc:1510: [0419/044955:INFO:host_resolver_impl.cc(1510)] HostResolverImpl::SetPreresolver preresolver:0x51d25d10
04-19 04:49:55.070: D/HostStatisticManager(11536): netstack: DNS Host Prioritization is: ON, Version: 5.0.1
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/(11536): external/chromium/net/socket/tcp_fin_aggregation_factory.cc: libtcpfinaggr.so successfully loaded
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/(11536): external/chromium/net/socket/tcp_fin_aggregation_factory.cc,: TCP Fin Aggregation initializing method was found in libtcpfinaggr.so
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/TCPFinAggregation(11536): netstack: TCPFinAggregation is 1, Version 5.0.1
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/TCPFinAggregation(11536): system property net.tcp.fin.aggregation.wait was set, value: 20
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/TCPFinAggregation(11536): system property net.tcp.fin.aggregation.close was set, value: 300
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/TCPFinAggregation(11536): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON, (TCPFinAggregation), Version 5.0.1
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/TCPFinAggregation(11536): Failed to get network status! received ret: -2
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/Socket_Pool(11536): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/Socket_Pool(11536): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/Socket_Pool(11536): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
04-19 04:49:55.080: D/Socket_Pool(11536): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
04-19 04:49:55.090: D/(11536): external/chromium/net/http/http_getzip_factory.cc: libgetzip.so successfully loaded
04-19 04:49:55.090: D/(11536): external/chromium/net/http/http_getzip_factory.cc,: GETzip initializing method was found in libgetzip.so
04-19 04:49:55.090: D/netstack(11536): netstack: Request Priority is ON
04-19 04:49:55.090: D/(11536): netstack: Getzip is: ON, Version: 5.0.1
04-19 04:49:55.180: D/WebKit(11536): ERROR: 
04-19 04:49:55.180: D/WebKit(11536): alias gb18030 maps to GB18030 already, but someone is trying to make it map to GBK
04-19 04:49:55.180: D/WebKit(11536): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/text/TextEncodingRegistry.cpp(152) : void WebCore::checkExistingName(char const*, char const*)
04-19 04:50:00.120: E/dalvikvm(11536): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1207K, 24% free 17251K/22599K, paused 5ms+7ms, total 350ms
04-19 04:50:02.810: D/AudioManager(11536): currentDeviceType = 1
04-19 04:50:02.870: V/FXActivity(11536): onPause
04-19 04:50:03.690: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11536): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-19 04:50:03.770: V/FXEntity(11536): Called Surface destroyed
04-19 04:50:03.780: V/FXActivity native(11536): [JVDBG] SURFACE created native android window at 0x0, surface = 0x0
04-19 04:50:03.790: I/GLASS(11536): Native code is notified that surface has changed (repaintall)!
04-19 04:50:04.210: W/ManagedEGLContext(11536): doTerminate failed: EGL count is 2 but managed count is 1
04-19 04:50:04.210: V/FXActivity(11536): onStop
04-19 04:50:04.210: V/FXActivity(11536): onDestroy
```

Comment: Is the `WebView` installed in the primary view?

Comment: No it's not (if primary view means "HOME_VIEW"). The `View` containing the `WebView` is the rootnode. As I mentioned I'm able to use a navigation button of the appBar to go back in the view history. So I guess the issue must be related to the webview?

Comment: I've done a test with a Multiple View project with FXML, adding a `WebView` to the secondary view, loading a very simple html file, and I can go back with the Android back button to the main view.

Comment: I've tried it as well. Exactly as you described, with the same result. When the webview is focused, pressing the back button closes the app. Android version is 4.1.1

Comment: Ok, `when the webview is focused` is the key to reproduce the issue. The Back button is not handled by the view stack. Instead there's a crash. I'll file a bug.

Comment: same here, created it on second view and it closes application.